Docusaurus build fails in cloudflare when I indude the ideal-image-plugin in its configuration file
this is log from cloudflare
    Executing user command: npm run build
    13:06:53.479    
    13:06:53.479    > pcbcupid@0.0.0 build
    13:06:53.480    > docusaurus build
    13:06:53.480    
    13:06:54.781    [INFO] [en] Creating an optimized production build...
    13:06:55.570    [info] [webpackbar] Compiling Client
    13:06:55.593    [info] [webpackbar] Compiling Server
    13:06:59.098    munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer
    13:06:59.113    Aborted
    13:06:59.124    Failed: Error while executing user command. Exited with error code: 134
    13:06:59.134    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
    13:07:01.550    Failed: error occurred while running build command, when this is included default    configurations of ideal image plugin.

I was integrating the ideal-image plugin to my docusaurus site, I got this error not locally but while deploying on cloudflare "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer".
